# Setting up sockets for distributed system communication

Tags: c++, c, linux, sockets

I am writing client/server distributed instance for chat implementation. I want each instance to  be capable of being server and client at the same time, so I am trying to assign both physical address (using bind, so other nodes could connect to node) and remote address (using connect, so the node could communicate with others). As far as I know this is impossible by sockets programming because bind/connect function can be used only once in a process. But if I want to send and receive messages (using sockets by send/recv functions) I don't see other possibility. Could you please tell me how to achieve mentioned above functionality (exchanging message through sockets by send/recv)? I am getting error (connect: Transport endpoint is already connected) if I try to use connect function after bind function like this:

```
if((*socket_handler = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1) {
    error("socket");
}
struct sockaddr_in socket_address;
socket_address.sin_family = AF_INET;
socket_address.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
socket_address.sin_port = htons(port);
if(bind(*socket_handler, (struct sockaddr*)&socket_address, sizeof(socket_address)) == -1) {
    error("bind");
}
if(listen(*socket_handler, 5) == -1) {
    error("listen");
}
if (port == port_to_connect) {
    return;
}

// is it ok to connect that way?
socket_address.sin_family = AF_INET;
socket_address.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
socket_address.sins_port = htons(port_to_connect);
if(connect(*socket_handler, (struct sockaddr*)&socket_address, sizeof(socket_address)) == -1) {
    error("connect");
}    am_i_pointing_to_myself = false;
```

Answer (score 2):

A TCP socket can either listen/accept, or it can connect, but it cannot do both.

Your application will likely need two separate threads. One thread would open a socket for listening, wait for a connection and handle that connection. The other one would makes a connection when the user requests it.

To keep things simple, the user thread that does the connection should send the user's message and close the connection, while the background listening thread should read a message from the accepted socket, display it to the user, and close the connection.

Another option is to have the application ask the user for server or client mode. For server mode, the app would listen and wait for a connection, then when it has a connection it can send back and forth over the connected socket. For client mode, it would make a connection to the server, then use the socket to communicate in both directions.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're using the same socket for both the listen() and the connect(). That is why you're getting that error.

You should be able to both listen and connect but you'll need a different socket for each.

What exactly are you trying to accomplish overall?

You said you need to have each instance be able to be a client or a server. That sounds like a P2P sort of thing.

Why do you need to both accept and make connections?

Comment: I have written that I need client/server instance(s) for exchanging messages by send/recv.

Comment: Yes, but for what reason or purpose?